Antd <Select> element with <Menu> as the dropdown list doesn't work, Can't load Menu.Item options
The const object defined as such
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const options = [
    {
      key: 'A',
      value: 'A',
      label: 'A'
    },
    {
      key: 'S',
      value: 'S',
      label: 'S'
    },
    {
      key: 'W',
      value: 'W',
      label: 'W'
    },
    {
      key: 'C',
      value: 'C',
      label: 'C'
    },
  ];

The Select element definition
<Select
              mode='multiple'
              value={selectedItems}
              defaultValue={options}
              showSearch={true}
              allowClear
              optionLabelProp='label'
              placeholder={
                <div>
                  {' '}
                  <img
                    src={xImg}
                    alt='xImg'
                    style={{ width: 14, height: 14, objectFit: 'cover' }}
                  />{' '}
                  &nbsp; Place Holder &nbsp;{' '}
                </div>
              }
              style={{ width: '100%' }}
              dropdownRender={  () => {
                <Menu style={{ width: 256, alignContent: 'center' }}>
                  {options.map((option) => (
                        <Menu.Item
                          key={option.key}
                          onClick={e => {
                            if (selectedItems.includes(option.label)) {
                              const newArray = selectedItems.filter(val => val !== option.label)
                              setSelectedItems(newArray)
                            } else {
                              const newArray = [...selectedItems, option.label]
                              setSelectedItems(newArray)
                            }
                          }}
                        >
                          {option.label}
                          <Checkbox style={{ float: 'left' }} checked={selectedItems.includes(option.label)} />
                        </Menu.Item>
                  ))}
                </Menu>
              }}
            />

Did I use the dropdownRender in the right way?
I tried disable value={} defaultValue={} and placeholder{} properties for select and also tried remove the onClick action for Menu.Item but doesn't help.

You just need to add before <Menu style.... But why you are using Menu here? If you want to customize the label of each option (i.e. add checkbox after the label), use labelRender.
